# Automate DB Schema Migrations - CircleCI/Sequelize/GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, circleci

I currently am working on an Application with a MySQL back-end hosted on GCP. Code is Node.js and we use CircleCI and Sequelize. Right now after deploying my scripts, if I had any schema changes, I would go in to the database and manually add those fields with sql scripts. We create migrations in our code and want to add those new field programmatically. I need to go in the container root and manually run the `npx sequelize db:migrate`. Is there a way to automate that?

For background info, I come from the database side not developer side, so please be gentle if my question seems to have an obvious answer.

Comment: You can achieve this. I am not sure what npx or sequelize does. What you can do is, let's say you have an sql file and you want to add that file to db. So, create a workflow and job. Include a step to copy the file to server. Later execute the command directly or through a shell script.

Comment: Thank you, npx is similar to npm. It is used for installing or executing commands. In my case I am using sequelize to migrate my changes which are part of the migrations created with our code deployment. So the code to make the schema changes is already with our migration. I was hoping there would be a way to automate the process without having to do any manual steps like copying the scripts or separately logging onto the root container and pasting the command ```npx sequelize db:migrate``` manually.

Comment: You should able to do this. I do use cassandra, what I do is, my circleci job copies the file we committed into server and using a command that migrates to the database, You should able to achieve the same. I do use python executor for the purpose.